# How to select different rows from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'am trying to get randomly 3 different rows from 2 tables with different fields

```
SELECT * FROM `models` JOIN banners WHERE `recomended` = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3
```

I want a result like this:

```
first row - table1.id table1.name table1.points
second row - table2.id table2.group table.2points
third row - table1.id table1.name table1.points
```

is that possible to do?

Comment: I think no. SQL return t1.id, t2.id, t3.id and in your system you organize this information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get what you want:

```
select id, name, points
from ((select  id, name, points, 1 as which
       from table1
       order by rand()
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select  id, group, points, 2 as which
       from table2
       order by rand()
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select  id, name, points, 3 as which
       from table1
       order by rand()
       limit 1
      )
     ) t
order by which;
```

Comment: I think this will always return 1 row from table 1 and two from table 2

Comment: @skv . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  It seems to clearly take two rows from table1 and one from table2.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I just interpreted the question to mean that at times the OP wanted random number of records from table1 and table2 so added an alternate version, sorry about saying table1 for 2 and vice-versa in my earlier comment